# Multiple buttons in grid

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I want to create a grid of total 15 buttons 5*3 style.
I have tried the in line and block method but when i try that they go out of sync.
I tried the following code

```
<html>
 <style>
 .group1 {

 padding: 20px 24px; /* Some padding */
 cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
 width: 40%; /* Set a width if needed */
display: block; /* Make the buttons appear 
   below each other */
   text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;

   }
 .group1:hover {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

.group1:not(:last-child) {
   border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double 
borders */
 }

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
 background-color: #3e8e41;
 }
 </style>
 <body>

 <h1>Vertical Button Group</h1>

 <div class="btn-group">
<div class="group1" type="button">Apple</div><br>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Samsung</div><br>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Sony</div>
</div>
```

This gives me 3 button in vertical line, I want to add same line twice in infront of it inline, how would I do that? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 .btn-group {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: inital;
}

.group1 {
  padding: 20px 24px;
  cursor: pointer; 
   text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;

.group1:hover {
 background-color: #3e8e41;
 }
```

```html
 <h1>Vertical Button Group</h1>

 <div class="btn-group">
<div class="group1" type="button">Apple</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Samsung</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Sony</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Apple</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Samsung</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Sony</div>
   <div class="group1" type="button">Apple</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Samsung</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Sony</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Apple</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Samsung</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Sony</div>
   <div class="group1" type="button">Apple</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Samsung</div>
 <div class="group1" type="button">Sony</div> 
</div>
```

Flexbox or CSS grid would be the answer, I just did a super fast example using grid.

Comment: this is perfect, i spent so much time trying to do this lol. thankyou so much for this :)

Comment: No worries, glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex` [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)